# Headphones stopped working in windows 8.1

Tags: audio, linux-mint, windows-8.1

So, I installed Linux mint 15 mate 64 bit on other partition, and a weird thing happened, I booted into Windows 8.1 and my headphones do not work. Realtek softwares notification pops up and recognizes that I connected headphones, but they do not work. I tried reinstalling drivers - didn't help and I tried Windows default drivers - when I use them, sound only comes through speakers rather then headphones.

Headphones work perfectly fine when booting into Linux mint, but in Windows 8.1 - problems.
Any ideas what should I do?

Comment: That's happend before with several distributions. You'll find similar questions if you google it. Probably Linux put your audio hardware in a state that Windows had troubles with. Try the following two suggestions: 1. Remove powercord en battery. Wait 5 mins. Reboot to Windows. 2. In Linux, if you use Pulseaudio, nano /etc/pulse/client.conf Uncomment the "autospawn" parameter and set it to "no" (autospawn = no)

Answer (score 1):

Try troubleshooting.

Steps:

1. Go to start menu and type 'Troubleshooting'.
2. Open it and click on 'Troubleshoot audio playback' in Hardware and Sound option.
3. Click Next, Choose Headphones and Windows will automatically detect the problem.
4. Click on 'Apply, fix' button and you're done!

(I tried doing it while connecting my headphones to the audio jack but sound was coming from the speakers and after doing troubleshooting.)

Answer (score -1):

Greeetings! Unplug headphones, plug in head phones, it will acknowledge it.
if it does not , download new driver from:

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035939

Comment: The OP said that he has unplugged and re-inserted his headphones. " Realtek softwares notification pops up and recognizes that I connected headphones". The OP has also reinstalled drivers "I tried reinstalling drivers - didn't help and I tried Windows default drivers". This adds nothing new to help the OP.